Can't use shared variable in NextJS 15
Minimal Code
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vqfy8t
Problem
I try to instantiate a class (Vault)
I wanted a variable to be shared among two routes in nextJS
/send-email/
    route.ts
/confirm-email/
    route.ts

What this variable does is to hold email id's with a generated code. and it confirms whether the code is valid or invalid.
this is the syntax for instantiating the vault class!
let instance: VaultType | undefined = undefined;
export function getOrCreateVaultInstance(keys?: Map<string, string>): Vault {
  if (instance === undefined) {
    console.info("✨ Creating a new vault instance ✨");
    instance = new Vault(keys);
  }

  return instance;
}

This is how i call vault (inside both send-email & confirm-email):
const vault = deps?.vault || getOrCreateVaultInstance();

deps are the optional params passed into the route functions. this is for the testing purposes only.
But why the vault gets instantiated twice? I want the vault to only create 1 instance, and it should be shared among two other routes or any other needed routes.
And Why is this happening?
What I want
to create a single instance among two nextJs routes.
I think the problem has to do with NextJS.
I'm on the latest version of NextJS (v.15)
As of chatGPT couldn't be helpful...
I've tried moving out the class and it's type to another file. And created a vaultSingleton.ts
file in order to create it only once.
I've tried to call getOrCreateVaultInstance once for every route file and then use it like this:
const vaultInstance = getOrCreatVaultInstance();

function POST(req, res, deps){ 
   const vault = deps?.vault || vaultInstance;
   // ...
}


Nothing changed. still saw the console.info("✨ Creating a new vault instance ✨"); twice...

Minimal Code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vqfy8t


That's so weird behavior and I have no idea why that happens. Tho can you try using the globalThis just like how prisma initializes their prismaClient https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/help-and-troubleshooting/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices Hope this helps.

It might be because of Module Caching in Node.js
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Module caching caveats
Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. Since modules may resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling module (loading from node_modules folders), it is not a guarantee that require('foo') will always return the exact same object, if it would resolve to different files.

My theory is that the send and confirm are importing the same vault module from different paths, That's why I think Node.js treats them as separate modules and creates a new Vault instance for each import, even though they are using the same module. Its better explained here.
send path:
app/api/send/../vault/vault
confirm path:
app/api/confirm/../vault/vault
The workaround I found is using the globalThis object
I tried using globalThis to your codesandbox and it only logged the ✨ Creating a new vault instance ✨ once with this code:
// Store the instance on globalThis for a singleton pattern
export function getOrCreateVaultInstance(keys?: Map<string, string>): Vault {
  if (!globalThis.__vaultInstance) {
    console.info(`✨ Created a vault instance ✨`);
    globalThis.__vaultInstance = new Vault(keys);
  }

  return globalThis.__vaultInstance;
}

// Type assertion to expose the instance as the Vault type
declare global {
  var __vaultInstance: Vault | undefined;
}

Here are some questions that I took the answer from:
Singleton pattern in nodejs - is it needed?
Hope this helps :)

It worked... But I won't mark this as an answer yet. I want to know why this behavior happens. And I don't think it's because of Module caching because if it were caching, it wouldn't create two instances. it has to do something with the next js, or next js file flags. like the ones we use to signal don't use cache. or noStore, etc...

Oh I see what you mean. From what I understood from the node docs, whats happening in your case is that getOrCreateVaultInstance is called on 2 different places. Thus since "... modules may resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling module, it is not a guarantee that require('foo') (import { getOrCreateVaultInstance } from ". . ." in your case) will always return the exact same object, if it would resolve to different files.", then I guess that's why you get different instances for confirm and send. Idk tho its just my guess.

I will modify my answer to explain this further.
